# Get the full formatted address from Reverse Geocoding

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

I want to retrieve the **full** formatted address via Google Maps API v3 Reverse Geocoding, since it only shows the postal code and/or city and country in many (maybe all) countries. I want to also retrieve the street name and the other stuff you can get through the [Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) function. But since I can't get data from XML files or addresses that are linked to an XML file in JavaScript, I must use the [Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse) function.

Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup) shows `791 Long Ridge Lane, Gainesboro, Tennessee 38562, USA` and Reverse Geocoding shows `Gainesboro, Tennessee 38562, USA`.

Is it possible to get the full formatted address even through Reverse Geocoding, or do I have to use the PHP XML file through Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup)?

```
function coordinates_to_address(lat, lng) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if(results[1]) {
                $('#address_current').text(results[1].formatted_address);
            } else {
                alert('No results found');
            }
        } else {
            var error = {
                'ZERO_RESULTS': 'Kunde inte hitta adress'
            }

            // alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
            $('#address_new').html('<span class="color-red">' + error[status] + '</span>');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the most precise result, use the first result (`results[0]`), not the second (`results[1]`):

```
function coordinates_to_address(lat, lng) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if(results[0]) {
                $('#address_current').text(results[0].formatted_address);
            } else {
                alert('No results found');
            }
        } else {
            var error = {
                'ZERO_RESULTS': 'Kunde inte hitta adress'
            }

            // alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
            $('#address_new').html('<span class="color-red">' + error[status] + '</span>');
        }
    });
}
```